# Bootstrap 3 image not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap config: http://www.bootply.com/118172

Could you tell me why the image isn't behaving responsively? I.e. I want it to shrink to be the same height as the div on the left hand side..

Comment: *I want it to shrink to be the same height as the div on the left hand side* what do you mean by this? You're hiding the image on smaller screens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap `img-responsive` is based on *width*, not height. This class will make the width 100% of it's container. If you want to make it the same height of the left div you can use..

```
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fPoX3wW.jpg" height="100" alt="Email">
```